# Detect webcam hardware with flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam

Is it possible to detect the specific webcam hardware that a person is using to stream through flash? Assuming that the user has accepted the webcam security questions and is successfully streaming to a FMS server; Can some code we written so that I can tell if the user is using a lifecam vs another model. Ie. are there headers or some other signature that can be used to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't used Flash Media Server.

The Camera class comes with a [names](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html#names) property and and [index](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html#index) property.
Names returns an array of the avaiable cameras and index returns the index of the selected camera, so you could in theory check if the user has that particular camera. Using a RegEx to find manufacturer matches, not a particular model might be handy.

something like:

```
function hasCamera(cameraName:String):Boolean{
   for(var i:int = 0; i < Camera.names.length; i++){
      if(Camera.names[i] == cameraName) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.